# Proof for the change of basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, change-of-basis

I wish to prove formally that the change of basis matrix $M$ is given by,

$$M=[I]_{\mathscr{B_{1}}}^{\mathscr{B_{2}}}$$

I wish to tidy up my proof, and would like someone to verify my steps.

**Proof.**

Let $\mathscr{B}_{1}=\{u_{1},u_{2},\ldots,u_{j},\ldots,u_{n}\}$ and $\mathscr{B}_{2}=\{w_{1},w_{2},\ldots,w_{j},\ldots,w_{n}\}$ be the two bases of the finite dimensional vector space $V$.

Suppose, the co-ordinates of $w_{j}$ with respect to the basis $\mathscr{B}_{1}$ are $\{a_{1j},a_{2j},\ldots,a_{nj}\}$. That is,

$$w_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}u_{i}$$

We also know that, for any transformation, the below relationship holds

$$[T(x)]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}=[T]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}\cdot[x]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}$$

So,

$$[I(w_{j})]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}=[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}^{\mathscr{B}_{1}}\cdot[w_{j}]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$$

But, $I(w_{j})=w_{j}$.

And $[w_{j}]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1j}\\a_{2j}\\\vdots\\{a_{nj}}\end{bmatrix}$. And $[w_{j}]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$ is like a standard basis vector with $j$th co-ordinate $1$.

The right hand side is the $j$th column of $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}^{\mathscr{B}_{1}}$.

---

My challenge here is, that, I wish to derive an expression for $M=[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$ and **not** $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}^{\mathscr{B}_{1}}$ . I know that, $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$ must represent the co-ordinates of the basis vectors of ${\mathscr{B}_{1}}$ relative to ${\mathscr{B}_{2}}$.

Comment: What is your definition of a change of basis matrix? I would think it would *be* $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, I read that it should be $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$. I want to find an expression for the same. I want to prove formally, that  $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$ are the co-ordinates of the basis vectors of ${\mathscr{B}_{1}}$ relative to ${\mathscr{B}_{2}}$.

Comment: I mean, unless you have another definition you're working from, there is nothing to prove. $[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}}$ is, *by definition* in most presentations, the change of basis matrix from $\mathscr{B}_{1}$to$\mathscr{B}_{2}$. 

$$[I]_{\mathscr{B}_{1}}^{\mathscr{B}_{2}} = [[Iu_1]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}} \ \cdots \ [Iu_n]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}] \\
=  [[u_1]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}} \ \cdots \ [u_n]_{\mathscr{B}_{2}}].$$

What is there to prove?